# Como alterar o minSdkVersion no Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tendo alguns problemas em executar no meu dispositivo real.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essse é em cima é meu dispositivo, e esse em baixo sãos as configuração do meu projeto.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.softblue.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{
            debuggable true
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Como faço para altera essa configuração para realidade do meu dispositivo real?

Comment: O minSdkVersion se encontra no arquivo de configuração da aplicação do Android, é o AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu projeto está setado a versão mínima como 21 
minSdkVersion 21 
Seu aparelho é Android 4.1.2 (API 16) certo? 
Então altere a sua minSdkVersion para 16.

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.softblue.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```